# Using sed to replace space delimited strings

Tags: regex, bash, sed

`echo 'bar=start "bar=second CONFIG="$CONFIG bar=s buz=zar bar=g bar=ggg bar=f bar=foo bar=zoo really?=yes bar=z bar=yes bar=y bar=one bar=o que=idn"' | sed -e 's/^\|\([ "]\)bar=[^ ]*[ ]*/\1/g'`

Actual output:

`CONFIG="$CONFIG buz=zar bar=ggg bar=foo really?=yes bar=yes bar=one que=idn"`

Expected output:

`CONFIG="$CONFIG buz=zar really?=yes que=idn"`

What I'm missing in my regex?

**Edit:**

This works as expected (with GNU `sed`):

`'s/\(^\|\(['\''" ]\)\)bar=[^ ]*/\2/g; s/[ ][ ]\+/ /g; s/[ ]*\(['\''"]\+\)[ ]*/\1/g'`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what it is you're asking for. You want to remove all matches of `bar=something`?

Comment: Yes
and `something` can be anything without space or newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed regular expressions are pretty limited. They don't include \w as a synonym for [a-zA-Z0-9_], for example. They also don't include \b which means the zero-length string at the beginning or end of a word (which you really want in this situation...).

```
s/ bar=[^ ]* *//
```

is close, but the problem is the trailing `*` removes the space that might precede the next `bar=`. So, in `... bar=aaa bar=bbb ...` the first match is `bar=aaa` leaving `bar=bbb ...` to try for the second match but it won't match because you already consumed the space before `bar`.

```
s/ bar=[^ ]*//
```

is better -- don't consume the trailing spaces, leave them for the next match attempt.  If you want to match `bar=something` even if it's at the beginning of the string, insert a space at the beginning first:

```
sed 's/^bar=/ bar=/; s/ bar=[^ ]*//'
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `s/^bar=/ &/; s/ bar=[^ ]*//'. The `&` is whatever substring was matched.

Comment: With a more modern regular expression engine (like in Perl or Python), you could just do this: `s/\bbar=\S+\s*//`. That matches `bar` but not `foobar`, followed by `=` and zero or more non-whitespaces, followed by zero or more whitespace.

Comment: None of your sed expressions seem to work for `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` as per the provided test case. What version is your sed?

Comment: I'm using 4.2.2 and got exactly the specified expected output.

Comment: `\w` is supported by GNU sed.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Apparently so is `\b`. The documentation says these are GNU extensions which are disabled in POSIXLY_CORRECT mode.

Comment: @Waxrat `'s/^\|\([" ]\)bar=[^ ]*/\1/g; s/[ ][ ]\+/ /g`' doesn't remove `bar=start` at the beginning of the text, can you explain why?

Comment: Operator precedence. `a|bc` matches `a` or `bc`, not `ab` or `ac`. You probably want `s/\(^\|[" ]\)bar=...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all instances of `bar=something` then you can simplify your regex as such:

`\sbar=\w+`

This matches all `bar=` plus all whole words. The `bar=` must be preceded by a whitespace character.

Demonstration:
https://regex101.com/r/xbBhJZ/3

As sed:

`s/\sbar=\w\+//g`

This correctly accounts for foobar=bar.

Like Waxrat's answer, you have to insert a space at the beginning for it to properly match as it's now matching against a preceding whitespace character before the `bar=`. This can be easily done since you're quoting your string explicitly.

Comment: The problem is this does match not only `bar=something` but also `foobar=something`; and I couldn't find `\s` in GNU `sed` manual, what is that?

Comment: I also don't see mention of \s listed in the help documentation for GNU sed. `\s` stands for "whitespace character" and is generally synonymous with space, tab, line break, and form feed. But it seems to be implementation-defined.